# GUI tool for viewing CPU/IO/Memory Pressure information in Linux

Tags: linux, monitoring, memory-management

Newer versions of the Linux kernel provide detailed information on not only memory pressure, but also IO and CPU pressure. This "pressure" can be thought of as a measure how much your computer is "fighting" for a particular resource, a useful indicator that you may be low on that particular resource and may want to think about upgrading your system or closing some programs to free things up a bit.

As a Linux user who has just upgraded to a distro based on the new Ubuntu 20.04 that supports this memory pressure API, is there any way that I can see this information in a GUI graph, rather than having to open a terminal and check the value each time?

Answer (score 1):

KDE distributions offer a built-in "Task Manager" called kSysGuard which has the capability to monitor remote machines through a small daemon/background process installed on a remote machine.

I found a script that mimics this background process, I was able to get the memory pressure information from `/proc` to show up as sensors that can be plotted or displayed just like any other sensor.

[image: screenshot of kSysGuard showing some of the custom memory pressure information as a graph]

[The script I used](https://github.com/MoralCode/MemoryPressure) is available to download on github and has some documentation along with it, including a bash script to generate a `.sgrd` file that can be imported as a tab into kSysGuard to provide the screenshot above as well as all the sensors to create your own graphs.